# beat someone to <noun> vs. beat someone to <-ing phrase>

Tags: grammar

First example:

> Leibnitz beat Newton to **publication** by three years

or

> Leibnitz beat Newton to **making it public** by three years

Second example: imagine two men are dueling and one wins the duel by killing the other, which is the correct comment to make?

> He beat him to **the shot**

or

> He beat him to **firing the shot**

I have seen the first sentence of each example before, I was wondering if it is correct to use the second sentences as well and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Smock mentions, these phrases have slightly different meanings. In both examples, the formersounds more common to my ears, whilst the latter -- although technically correct -- means something different, and perhaps by coincidence quite rarely expressed.

I would say that in both cases the former example (*i.e.* "beat ... to publication" and "beat him to the shot") would be more palatable to a native-speakers ears.

Comment: thanks for the explanation